# My muting app doesn't mute ALL the sounds

Tags: android, mute

Hey guys I am learning about android development, and I am working through a book that is showing me how to make an app that toggles mute on and off. I can get my app to go to vibrate like I want, but I need help to get all the sounds off. When I go into another app like draw something, I will get the sounds from that app. I looked around and what I found was to mute the STREAM_MUSIC. This is what I wrote.

```
if(mPhoneIsSilent)
        {
            mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(STREAM_MUSIC, true);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        }
```

But I still get the sound from other apps. Am I using the right streamType?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry guys it was just a dumb mistake..I should have wrote it like this..  `code` mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManger.STREAM_MUSIC, true);